# a simple select SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using sql server 2008 R2 and I have tables:

```
Book: id, name, ...  >> 3500 rows
BookChapter: id, bookid, content(nvarchar(max)... >> it has about 300000 rows
```

No relationship between the 2.

now i want to count all books that currently have no chapters.

```
SELECT     COUNT(Id) AS Expr1
FROM         dbo.Book
WHERE     (Id NOT IN  (SELECT BookId FROM dbo.BookChapter))
```

always gives timeout expired. How can i achieve it?

Comment: Are you getting a SQL time out in the SQL Server Management Studio or is the Application you are calling it timing out?

Comment: timed out in sqlmanagement studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use a left join its similar to not exists but sometime performs better.

```
select count(1) as Counts
from 
    dbo.Book B
    left join dbo.BookChapter BC on BC.BookID = B.ID
where
    BC.BookID is null
```

Comment: It would be interesting if you report the query execution time of all the answers. This would only be fair if you have an index on bookid in chapters, which you really should have.

Comment: @apartridge the left join above show instantly, almost 0ms and the result is correct, whereas other subqueries get timed out expiry in Sql management studio. No result.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery gets very large. You may try grouping it by BookId.

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) AS Expr1
FROM   dbo.Book
WHERE  (Id NOT IN  (SELECT BookId FROM dbo.BookChapter GROUP BY BookId))
```

Another option using `NOT EXISTS`;

```
SELECT COUNT(B.Id) AS count
FROM   dbo.Book B
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.BookChapter WHERE BookId=B.BookId))
```

Comment: thanks for prompt reply. It's still not efficient, still timeout.

Comment: Do you have an index `BookId` on `BookChapter`?

Comment: oh sorry i'm new to sql, and fulltext index as well. I'll try to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use "not in".  It's too slow.  You can use "not exists" as per apartidge's second suggestion, or you can do something completely unintuitive like this:

```
select count(*) BooksWithoutChapters
from book
where id in 
(select id
from book
minus 
select bookid
from BookChapter
)
```